# How do I disable individual components of an app's APK?

Tags: rooting, system

[ROM Toolbox Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro)'s app manager had this feature but it has been removed in recent versions. 
Specifically I'm looking at disabling individual components of an APK, `AdActivity` for example.

I have already seen questions on doing this programmatically on Stack Overflow, which involve recompiling it - running into signing problems later.

I'm looking for an easier way to disable activities, services and content providers.

Comment: [MyAndroidTools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools) (and its Pro variant) fits very well, been using it to this day. Will move it to an answer if the question gets reopened.

Comment: Take a look at [Auto-Start Manager](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_autostart#group_847) apps then. Assuming you chose the `rooting` tag to indicate you have `root-access`, that will be needed to disable activities separately. In the past (some years ago) I had good experiences with *Autorun Manager* in this context (can be found behind that link).

Comment: I guess you are talking about advanced freeze, how about using [Disable service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice) or something like Tasker to disable the services programatically

Comment: i.e `am stopservice com.package.name/.service name`

Answer (score 2):

[MyAndroidTools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools) (and its [Pro variant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtoolspro)) fits very well - offers control on activities, services, receivers and providers, and if you get Pro you can also conveniently peek into and edit apps' SharedPreferences and databases, so that's what you require and then some more.

Requires root, but that's pretty much a given for this kind of app.

Comment: This has been since removed from the Play Store, for anyone else looking for a solution. SOL at the moment unless there's anything else.

Comment: The app hasn't been updated since April anyway, but if you sideload via an APK it'd still work.

Comment: It's living on borrowed time, I wouldn't count on it working indefinitely, which is why I was looking for a more recent alternative.